# Vue js PATCH http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/profile 401 (Unauthorized)

Tags: laravel, api, vue.js

I have a modal where I can create edit users. But when I click on the submit button I got a 401 error.

and I want to change the name without update page
The method looks like this:

---

```
    if(token){
      this.preformUpdate();
    }
  },
  methods: {
    preformUpdate: function() {
      this.loading = true;
      this.msgupdate = "Updated your profile";
      this.alert = true;
      axios
        .patch("/profile", {
          name: this.name,
          token: this.token
        })
        .then(response => {
          const name = localStorage.setItem("name", response.data.user.name);
          this.email = localStorage.getItem("email");
          console.log(response.data.user.name);
          this.loading = false;
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
          this.error = error.message;
          this.loading = false;
        });
    }
  }
```

Comment: What's `token`? are you getting the bearer api_token key correctly? console.log(token); to make sure

Comment: yes ... and code (if (taken)) find in function mounted